# The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "advanced_pricing_button" component. | Upgrade Magento 2.0.7 => 2.1.0

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

After a lot of issues I managed to update Magento 2.0.7 => Magento 2.1.0

After checking the upgrade I see 2 issues:
1. The frontend is not displaying any products.
2. When I want to edit the products in the admin, I get the following error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "advanced_pricing_button" component.

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "advanced_pricing_button" component.
#0 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(360): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array, Array, false)
#1 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(360): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array, Array, false)
#2 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(360): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array, Array, false)
#3 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(272): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array, Array, false)
#4 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadata('product_form', Array, false)
#5 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('product_form', NULL, Array)

#6 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'product_form', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#7 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#8 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#9 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#10 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#11 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#12 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(244): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#13 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(859): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#14 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php(59): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('menu')
#15 /home/tm/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog...')
#16 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Edit.php(69): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog...')
#17 /home/tm/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit->execute()
#18 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->execute()
#19 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#22 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#23 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#26 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /home/tm/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#29 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#32 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#33 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /home/tm/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#36 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 /home/tm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#38 /home/tm/public_html/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#39 {main}
```

Did anyone fixed this issue?

Comment: I've got the same problem after updating from Magento 2.0.7 to Magento 2.1. Check out the issue on Github for more information: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5236

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/137894)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Had the same issue when migrating from Magento 2.0.7 to 2.1.0, the following WAR described on https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5236 fixed the problem for me:

In `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/ConfigurablePrice.php` look for the following code:

```
$meta[$groupCode]['children'][self::CODE_GROUP_PRICE] = array_replace_recursive(
    $meta[$groupCode]['children'][self::CODE_GROUP_PRICE],
    [
        'children' => [
            self::$advancedPricingButton => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => $visibilityConfig,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]
);
```

And replace the following line:

```
'config' => $visibilityConfig,
```

With:

```
'config' => ['componentType'=>'container',$visibilityConfig],
```

If you don't see any fields populated in your Magento product catalog BE then check some other products. In my case some products would show the following error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 118 in
>   /......./vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/ResourceModel/ReadHandler.php
>   on line 166

This happens because table `catalog_product_entity_varchar` contains an attribute which doesn't exist in other tables, in my case the problem went away by just removing the entries with the `attribute_id` listed in the error above:

```
mysql> delete from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id=XXXXXXX;
Query OK, 7890 rows affected (0.11 sec)
```

Make sure you **back up your database** before you start hacking away!

Comment: If you don't see any fields populated in your Magento product catalog BE or get the following error then follow steps below:

Comment: After changing the code it gives me an error `Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Media does not exist`.  Any solution to this?

Comment: Sorry, no idea...

Comment: I... love you ? Quite a lot.

Comment: Is this fixed now in magento 2?

Comment: How can we debug this type of error? Actually, I am getting `The configuration parameter “componentType” is a required for “” component` in the product edit page in the second store. However, the default store is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 
`The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "" component`
error without anything in quotes, that means you have in current attribute set an attribute group named the same way as some attribute.
For example creating a "Weight" attribute group will bring this error.
So you need to rename or delete (after moving all attributes to another group) such attribute group.