# After upgrade from 2.0.6 to 2.1.2 no products show up, all categories are empty

Tags: magento-2.1, products, upgrade, category-products, category-tree

I'm sure this question has been asked, but there is no answer, and now it is critical that I upgrade from 2.0.6 due to the new advisory.

I have tried several different ways to upgrade, via CLI with composer and magento:upgrade ala this guide

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

I have tried fresh install from scratch only using my previous database and installing with the composer.

the end result for both is a page that has the category tree, but all products do not exist, yet the product count on the side within the category tree is the full count of all products including products not in inventory.

I've done just about everything imaginable, I've reindexed, I've flushed the cache, I've verified permissions.

In the admin, I can see all of my products, and all of my categories are populated with all my products

any pointers any suggestions, I'm practically at my wit's end.

Answer (score 1):

Answer source : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5236

Fix for showing products on category page: 
Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Configuration::getDefaultScopeId()

replace

```
public function getDefaultScopeId()
{
    // TODO: should be fixed in MAGETWO-46043
    // "0" is id of admin website, which is used in backend during save entity
    return 0;
}
```

with

```
public function getDefaultScopeId()
{
    // TODO: should be fixed in MAGETWO-46043
    // "0" is id of admin website, which is used in backend during save entity
    $scopeId = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getId();
    return $scopeId;
}
```

also look at the following question if you have an issue to edit the products in backend

[The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "advanced_pricing_button" component. | Upgrade Magento 2.0.7 => 2.1.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123994/the-configuration-parameter-componenttype-is-a-required-for-advanced-pricing)

Comment: ill have to reinstall 2.1.2 again, so give me till the end of the day and i will let you know if this works, I will also comment on the thread if it does and let them know my issue and what happened, etc etc.  thanks for the lead