# "The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "advanced_pricing_button" component."

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent

I have a weird issue:

Whenever i try to edit a product i get a error screen and in the report it display:

> The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for
>   "advanced_pricing_button" component.

I tried to follow the steps listed here: [The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "advanced_pricing_button" component. | Upgrade Magento 2.0.7 => 2.1.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123994/the-configuration-parameter-componenttype-is-a-required-for-advanced-pricing)

But now only the words `advanced_pricing_button` are gone from the error report and it's still failing over the same element as I dumped the data element it's failing over.

```
"The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "" component."
```

Any thoughts ?

Here is the throw it's getting into:

```
if (!$isMerged) {
            if (!isset($data['arguments']['data']['config']['componentType'])) {
                throw new LocalizedException(new Phrase(
                    '<pre>'.print_r($data).'</pre>',
                    'The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "%1" component.',
                    [$name]
                ));
            }
```

And this is the print_r of the $data element.
As you see the throw is based on

```
!isset($data['arguments']['data']['config']['componentType']
```

however that is set in the element so the throw should never be made.

```
Array ( 
            [advanced_pricing_button] => Array ( 
                [arguments] => Array ( 
                    [data] => Array ( 
                        [config] => Array ( 
                            [displayAsLink] => 1 
                            [formElement] => container 
                            [componentType] => container 
                            [component] => Magento_Ui/js/form/components/button 
                            [template] => ui/form/components/button/container 
                            [actions] => Array ( 
                                [0] => Array ( 
                                    [targetName] => product_form.product_form.advanced_pricing_modal 
                                    [actionName] => toggleModal 
                                ) 
                            ) 
                            [title] => Magento\Framework\Phrase Object ( 
                                [text:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => Advanced Pricing 
                                [arguments:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => Array ( ) 
                            ) 
                            [additionalForGroup] => 1 
                            [provider] => [source] => product_details 
                            [sortOrder] => 121 
                        ) 
                    ) 
                ) 
            ) 
        )
```

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I also get the same issue when upgrade magento to 2.4. And I found that change the value of eav_attribute_group.attribute_set_id=4 to "product-details", then it works find. seems in 2.4 all of the default attribute group is "product-details", the words "product-details" is exactly hard code in magento source code.