# The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "" component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I am using Magento version. 2.2.6. When I navigate to add product and select specific attribute set "Test"

I am getting error

> main.ERROR: The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required
>   for "" component. [] []
>
> **Note:** I am not getting this error by selecting other attribute sets. Please help.

Comment: can you Add some code in Your Question

Comment: @WaqarAli: Sorry I can not add code, I just created attribute sets simply. I do not know why this error is coming because day before all things was working perfectly.

Comment: this might help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123994/the-configuration-parameter-componenttype-is-a-required-for-advanced-pricing

Comment: I did go through it already. As I am using 2.2.6 and as I said there was no error on day before. Also, I can not reproduce error on local and staging server.